# enviroment variable to hashmap

Tags: java, spring-el

In my application yml I create an environment variable reference for consumerTypeMappings

```
  kafka:
    consumerTypeMappings: 
      ${OG_TEST_CUSTOM_TYPE_MAPPINGS:}
```

within environment variables (in eclipse run configuration tab) I create an entry for it

```
OG_TEST_CUSTOM_TYPE_MAPPINGS="com.og.test.events.DomainObjectInsideEvent":
 "com.og.test.events.OgTestConsumerEventWithDomainObject"
```

And this **works**, it's successfully parsed into the map I need

However when I add a second entry, like so:

```
OG_TEST_CUSTOM_TYPE_MAPPINGS="com.og.test.events.DomainObjectInsideEvent": "com.og.test.events.OgTestConsumerEventWithDomainObject"**,"com.og.test.events.JsonNodeEvent":
"com.og.test.events.JsonNodeEventTwo"**
```

it fails with error

```
No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String]
  to type [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>]
```

---

update to show use:

```
public class KafkaCustomJsonDeserializer<T> extends JsonDeserializer<T> {
    public static final String TYPE_ID_MAPPINGS = "com.avispl.symphony.kafka.typeid.mappings";
    private static final String TYPE_ID_HEADER = "__TypeId__";
    private Map<String, String> typeIdMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public synchronized void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
        if (!isKey) {
            typeIdMap = (Map<String, String>) configs.get(TYPE_ID_MAPPINGS);
        }

        super.configure(configs, isKey);
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(String topic, Headers headers, byte[] data) {
        Headers customHeaders = null;
        // replace type id header if replacement is configured
        if (!typeIdMap.isEmpty()) {
            if (headers != null) {
                Iterable<Header> iterable = headers.headers(TYPE_ID_HEADER);
                if (iterable != null) {
                    byte[] value = null;
                    for (Header header : iterable) {
                        value = header.value();
                        // should be only one type id header
                        break;
                    }

                    if (value != null) {
                        try {
                            String typeId = new String(value, "UTF-8");
                            String customTypeId = typeIdMap.get(typeId);
                            if (customTypeId != null) {
                                customHeaders = new RecordHeaders(headers.toArray());
                                customHeaders.remove(TYPE_ID_HEADER);
                                customHeaders.add(TYPE_ID_HEADER, customTypeId.getBytes());
                            }
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            // TODO report error!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return super.deserialize(topic, customHeaders != null ? customHeaders : headers, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are setting the deserializer `config` map entry, it should be a simple comma-delimited list:

```
OG_TEST_CUSTOM_TYPE_MAPPINGS="com.og.test.events.DomainObjectInsideEvent:com.og.test.events.OgTestConsumerEventWithDomainObject,com.og.test.events.JsonNodeEvent:com.og.test.events.JsonNodeEventTwo"
```

Or, show how you are using `consumerTypeMappings` in your code.

Comment: see updates.  i had it working as a string (like you shown).  i just thought it a bit more straightforward to have it come in as a map instead of needing to parse a delimited string

Comment: I get that error even with one map entry. The `JsonSerializer` has a static method to create the map (also used by the deserializer), but it is not public; we can make it public so users can use it.